# UWP - NavigationView Control - PaneDisplayMode property is absent

Tags: uwp, windows-10, uwp-xaml, winui

Sorry this seems to be a dumb question, but really I have no clue!

I'm writing an UWP app. Trying to put up the NavigationView Control in the MainPage, and set the navigation bar at top, not left.

So this should be easily implemented with...

```
  <NavigationView PaneDisplayMode="Top">
        <NavigationView.MenuItems>
            <NavigationViewItem Content="Design" Tag="DesignPage" />
            <NavigationViewItem Content="Settings" Tag="SettingsPage" />
            <NavigationViewItem Content="Library" Tag="LibraryPage" />
        </NavigationView.MenuItems>
    </NavigationView>
```

The IDE VS2017 (community) says "The Property 'PaneDisplayMode' was not found in type 'NavigationView'." !!!

Everything is pretty up to date in the IDE.

Project target version is Win10 1803 Build 17134

Min version is Win10 FallCreators Update Build 16299

In project References, there is the 'Universal Windows' fixed reference, it properties says Version = 10.0.17134.0
the Win10 installed in my computer is version 1803

[image: PaneDisplayMode is absent]

This property should appear, as is stated in this webpage reference manual
[Microsoft Dev Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.navigationview.panedisplaymode)

What can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`PaneDisplayMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.navigationview.panedisplaymode#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_NavigationView_PaneDisplayMode) was introduced in 1809, So it's normal.

If you still want to use this property, you can use [`NavigationView from WinUI`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.navigationview) . With WinUI, you can use the most recent Updated UIs while keeping your Min Target to a much lower Version of Windows.

To know how to use WinUI in you project, visit [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/toolkits/winui/getting-started)

Comment: thanks for reply, tried WinUI from nuget.
but build gives error
Microsoft.UI.Xaml nuget package requires TargetPlatformVersion >= 10.0.17763.0 (current project is 17134)

Comment: tried to update the OS, but the OS itself doesn't allow me to do this

Comment: try restarting the IDE

Comment: TargetPlatformVersion >= 10.0.17763.0 means WinUI requires SDK >= 10.0.17763.0, and the app can run on all of the OS from TargetPlatformMinVersion to TargetPlatformVersion without any problem. You only need to install 17763 SDK. Launch visual studio installer, then modify and add Windows SDK (10.0.17763.0 )